# Why "long value" equals to null is allowed?

Tags: c#, .net

When I was debugging a few lines of code and asking me why on earth it wasn't working I have stumbled on this situation ...

```
if(answer.AnswerID == null) 
{
    // do something
}
```

When in fact it should be this way:

```
if(answer == null)
{
    // do something
}
```

- `answer` is an object of the type `Answer - a class`.
- `AnswerID` is a property of type `long`.

The weird thing is that if you try something like this:

```
long myLongValue = null;
```

The compiler will show you an error:

```
Connot convert null to long ...
```

So my question is: Why did I not get a **compile error** when I was trying to compare a `long type` with `null`?

**EDITED**

This question **IS NOT** about `nullable` types.

I'm asking WHY .NET allows me to compare a long variable with null. I'm talking about `long type` and not about `long? type`.

Comment: Is it of type `long?` or `long`?

Comment: Are you asking why answer.AnswerID == null doesn't cause a compilation error because as AnswerID is a long it can never be null?

Comment: You get a compiler warning that tells you more. The compiler assumes a `Nullable<long>` even if it's `long`.

Comment: @CodeCaster: How does this question duplicate that one? There is no mention of a nullable type within the question (and apparently, it's not a mistake).

Comment: Isn't it `long?` ? (mind the question mark!)

Comment: @BoltClock I asked a question followed by a close vote for a _possible_ duplicate with what in my opinion was the most obvious cause. OP's reply negated this, so I retracted it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As [@Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21111534/why-long-value-equals-to-null-is-allowed/21111655#comment31762641_21111534) pointed out, you won't get an error for the following code:

```
long foo = 42;

if (foo == null) { }
```

You'll get a warning instead:

> The result of the expression is always 'false' since a value of type 'long' is never equal to 'null' of type 'long?'.

This gives a warning instead of an error because of [lifted operators](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/06/27/what-exactly-does-lifted-mean.aspx), defined in the C# language specification as such:

> ***Lifted operators*** permit predefined and user-defined operators that operate on non-nullable value types to also be used with nullable forms of those types. [...] For the equality operators
>
> ```
> ==  !=
> ```
>
> a lifted form of an operator exists if the operand types are both non-nullable value types and if the result type is bool. **The lifted form is constructed by adding a single ? modifier to each operand type.** The lifted operator considers two null values equal, and a null value unequal to any non-null value. If both operands are non-null, the lifted operator unwraps the operands and applies the underlying operator to produce the bool result.

The "underlying operator" in this case is [the predefined value type `long`'s `==` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth(v=vs.120).aspx):

> For predefined value types, the equality operator (==) returns true if the values of its operands are equal, false otherwise.

Because `foo` is implicitly converted (*"Predefined implicit conversions that operate on non-nullable value types can also be used with nullable forms of those types.")* and the `null` literal is also implicitly converted (*"An implicit conversion exists from the null literal to any nullable type."*), the expression:

```
(long)foo == null
```

Becomes:

```
(long?)foo == (long?)null
```

Which, given `foo` is of type `long` and thus always has a value, always returns false and won't even apply `long`'s `==` operator.

I'm not entirely sure, but I suspect this to exist to enable comparison between nullable and non-nullable values without explicit casting:

```
long? foo = 42;
long bar = 42;

Console.WriteLine(foo == bar); // true

foo = null;
Console.WriteLine(bar == foo); // false
```

If this wasn't handled by the language as specified above, you'd get *"Operator `==` cannot be applied to operands of type `long?` and `long`"*, because [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't have an `==` operator, and `long` doesn't have an `==` operator accepting a `long?`.

Comment: +1 But it's still not clear why `==` uses `CompareTo`. I've seen that [`Int64.CompareTo(object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19s77ktz(v=vs.110).aspx) explicitly allows `null` or `Int64`(`long`). Is this method used, if so, why?

Comment: @Tim see the last edit, please correct me if I'm wrong. So as far as I understand, no, `Int64.CompareTo()` is not called, because `long`'s  `==` (_"the underlying operator"_) will only be applied if both operands are not `null`.

Comment: @CodeCaster: seems to be the reason. However, i'm still waiting for E. Lippert ;)

Comment: This does not work for user defined structs. So reasoning is not correct.

Comment: Define `struct str{}` and try to compare its instance with null, it will give you compiler error. But for `long` just warning.

Comment: @Sergey that complies with my explanation, it doesn't contradict it. Try creating an `==` operator in your struct accepting two `str`s and seeing whether it gets called when comparing an instance with `null` (it doesn't), now try creating an `==` operator for `str?` (which _does_ get called). If you don't create the _"underlying operator"_, there's nothing the compiler can call for your `==`, and it'll throw an error. The `==` operator is predefined for `long`, not for user-defined structs. Try `new str() == new str()`.

Comment: Operator `==` is predefined for `long` ? Did not see this fact in your answer and did not see this in decompiled .NET sources. Please paste this piece of code to your answer.

Comment: @CodeCaster So, the conclusion is ... The compiler will not show me an error, because, in fact, there is no error at all. And that is because this weird (at least to me) behaviour. Is that correct?

Comment: It's not even always a mistake to compare a non-nullable type with null, as with generics we could have `if(someValue == null)` where `someValue` is of a generic type that might be non-nullable, but we want to do something in the case that it is nullable (and indeed, null). The fact that some instances will mean a non-nullable type is compared with null causes a (different) warning, because often what one really wants is `if(someValue == default(T))`, but there are times when the comparison to null is indeed exactly what one wants.

Answer (score 9):

It will compile and it will even execute because the compiler evaluates the `==` and promotes the `long` to `long?` because that is the closest match to an `==` implementation that exists.

This is indeed not the best of behaviors, it's kind of like VB :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) for information about nullable types. Ordinary value types like long and int can't be made null ordinarily.

The reason it didn't fail when you tried to compare it to null was because it did the comparison and it wasn't null. So no error there.

Comment: Can't, but can be compared to null, question is different