# Why can "!=" not be compared to a long?

Tags: c#, null, httpwebrequest, long-integer

I've got code like this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
. . .
if (null != request.UserAgent)
{
    str = String.Format("userAgent == {0}", request.UserAgent.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(str);
}
. . . // many other similar ones, comparing null to string, etc. types
```

But this one:

```
if (null != request.ContentLength)
{
    str = String.Format("contentLength == {0}", request.ContentLength.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(str);
}
```

...fails with a compile-time error of, "*Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type '' and 'long'*"

I can append a ToString() to get it to compile:

```
if (null != request.ContentLength.ToString())
. . .
```

...but that seems kind of weird. Why is HttpWebRequest's ContentLength (a long) uncomparable to null?

Comment: a long can never be null. You would have to have a long?/Nullable<long> for it to even get a null value.

Comment: Why? What makes long distinct from other data types in that way?

Comment: int, long, double, float etc can number be null as they are not nullable types because they are value types.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon, long is a value type, value types cannot be null.  It is not unique, all structs are value types.

Comment: Well damn looks like I should have put my comment as an answer to have gotten some points. ;)

Comment: @Cubicle.Jockey I upvoted your comment, but wouldn't do the same for an answer. It is, I think, every c# programmer should have already known.

Comment: @L.B I can see how being self taught you may miss something here or there. but yeah I was curious about that too. His reputation is far far greater than mine seems like a weird question.

Comment: I thought this was merely a warning? - `The result of the expression is always 'true' since a value of type 'long' is never equal to 'null' of type 'long?'.` due to an implicit conversion to `long?` - [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21111534/why-long-value-equals-to-null-is-allowed) question explains what I'm on about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ContentLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.contentlength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is an `Int64` which is not a nullable type. A `string` can be `null`, hence the conversion to a string allows the comparison.

Comment: But `ContentLength.ToString()` will never return `null`.

Answer (score 2):

That's because `long` is a value type and value types can never be null.

If you would like to assign null to a primitive type such as `int`, `long, double` etc you can by declaring it like this:

```
 long? myLong = null;
```

Comment: Probably not in my case, where I'm using .NET 0.9 on Windows for Workgroups with a clacky keyboard, rounded monitor, and blinking green cursor (slight exaggerations only).